# How to install numpy with PyCharm on mac OSX?

Tags: macos, numpy, pycharm

I downloaded the binary file and all it does is open up PyCharm. How can I install? Many thanks.

Comment: I dont understand your question. You can install it just via `pip install numpy` or `brew install numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. And I solved it like this: File/Default Settings...

Chose Default Project/Project Interpreter

Chose the version of Python you are working with from the popup menu Project Interpreter.

Below the list click on the '+' button. Find your way in the huge list of Packages available to find 'numpy' and install it.

There is probably another way to make it per project, but I assume that you want numpy in all project (it is my case).

Answer (score 0):

You drag it to wherever you want it... There's [no step 2, much less step 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHzM4avGrKI).