# install numpy for pycharm on mac

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I'm completely new to Python, and just downloaded Anaconda with a professional license. I then cloned a GitHub repository into PyCharm to work on as my first project.

PyCharm (which I've never used before) fails on the first line of code:

```
import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm with Anaconda plugin .app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

My understanding is that Anaconda should have "shipped" with numpy, scipy, and some other key packages. I get that PyCharm isn't finding that somehow, but how do I redirect it? I'm using a Mac and PyCharm 2020.1. Some of the [other help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495458/how-to-install-numpy-with-pycharm-on-mac-osx) said to install packages from the "settings" tab or file/default settings, but neither of those buttons exist in this version of the IDE. I also tried installing numpy in the Python console box based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575113/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy) but that didn't work either:

```
pip3 install numpy
  File "<input>", line 1
    pip3 install numpy
               ^
```

How do I get PyCharm to "find" the software that I supposedly downloaded with Anaconda?

**Edit:** I managed to open the python interpreter for this project and install numpy with the "+" button, but it still gives this error when I run `import numpy as np`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm with Anaconda plugin .app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

**Edit 2**: this error went away after restarting PyCharm... I'm surprised that's necessary after installing a package.

Comment: In PyCharm, press Ctrl + Alt + S and go to Project > Project Interpreter and click on + button and Install any desired package for your specific Project.

Comment: @DevanshSoni nothing happens when I try that shortcut in PyCharm on a Mac (or every other combination of keystrokes + s that I can think of), unless I'm missing something

Comment: In right bottom corner, Your python version is mentioned along with your project name. Click on that to go to Project Interpreter Settings.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. You can install it using 'Terminal' ( In left bottom corner ) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between PyCharm and Anaconda is that PyCharm is a quite convenient IDE and Anaconda is a set of python libraries. What I can recommend you right now:
**(do it in your terminal (⌘+space -> terminal) or in PyCharm's terminal)**:

`pip3 install numpy`

The error you show seems like you tried to run it not in the terminal, but in python's console box :/

Also - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830476/what-is-the-difference-between-anaconda-and-pycharm/36830516) is a nice way to connect Anaconda's libraries to PyCharm

**For installing libraries via PyCharm preferences:** 
 1. Click on the "PyCharm" -> "Preferences" [image: path] 
 2. Click on "Project Interpreter" and go for "+" button [image: add package]
 3. Type "numpy" and "install package"[image: install package]

Comment: you're right re terminal, oops! but I get this message: `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.16.3)` suggesting that I did install numpy, but then pycharm can't find it when I run `import numpy as np`.

Comment: Try to run it in Python console in PyCharm
Also - if needed - let`s add a "project interpreter". You can do it in "PyCharm" -> "Preferences" (⌘,) -> "Project" -> "Project Interpreter". You can choose any interpreter for starting (probably you have several)

Comment: thanks! I had to close and reopen PyCharm but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1:

Pycharm Preferences => Phyton interpreter

2:

Select Project interpreter

3:

Select the add button ( + )

4:

in search bar search for numpy

5:

Install package.

If you still got errors

No module named 'numpy'

Then go to Terminal left bottom corner of PyCharm software.

Then install numpy.

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: There is no "settings" option under "file" in this version of PyCharm!

Comment: Which version of PyCharm you are using?

Comment: 2020.1. I think some of this info is now in pycharm -> preferences

Comment: Use the **Edited** Answer it will work. I have tested.

Comment: thanks! this works to install numpy, but I still can't import it into pycharm!